# OmniAuth Not Working with Jquery Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, omniauth

I am trying to make a call to facebook connect via Jquery Ajax call. The call works if I am just using a link, but fails with the Ajax call. I am a novice with jquery and have difficulty even debugging it, as all I get is an alert saying error. Here is the ajax call:

```
$('a.fb_connect_button').click(function () { 
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://www.nutranation.org/users/auth/facebook',
      success: function(data) {
        $(".thankyou_box").show();
      },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(xhr.statusText);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
    });

})
```

here is the link that actually works: `<a class="fb_connect_button" href="http://www.nutranation.org/users/auth/facebook">`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a simple :rel => "external" to bypass the ajax request. Something like :

```
<%= link_to "facebook", "/auth/facebook", :rel => "external" %>
```